# stringFromDate returning the wrong year

Tags: nsdate

```
#define stdDateFormat @"YYYYMMdd'T'hh:mm:ssZ"
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:stdDateFormat];
NSString *TimeOfSync = [dateFormat stringFromDate:syncDate];
NSLog(@"date format: %@",stdDateFormat);
NSLog(@"syncDate: %@",syncDate);
NSLog(@"TimeOfSync: %@",TimeOfSync);
```

Logged output:

```
date format: YYYYMMdd'T'hh:mm:ssZ
syncDate: 2009-01-03 19:00:00 +0000
TimeOfSync: 20080103T11:00:00-0800
```

Can anyone help?  The only thing I can see is the extra space just before the timezone in the input date string. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use lowercase yyyy for the year instead of YYYY.

Uppercase Y means the year of the start of the ***week*** the date is in (Jan 3, 2009 is in a week that starts in 2008).

See [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thank you so much...this has been driving me CRAZY!  Such a simple solution to something has been driving me batty.  If I could up vote you multiple times, I would!

Comment: Upvoted, thanks! But just to note, it looks (according to the way this just happened to me, with dates two weeks ago showing as "Dec 30, 2016") like Y means "year the week is considered part of" according to the ISO year-week calendar. So "YYYY" doesn't necessarily show the year that the week *started* on.